# LibGDX - draw a shape in middle of zIndex of a group

Tags: libgdx, z-index, scene2d

I want to draw a filled circle in the middle of a `group` containing two `images`.

I've tried doing it with

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.end();

    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    renderer.setTransformMatrix(batch.getTransformMatrix());
    renderer.translate(getX(), getY(), 0);

    renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    renderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, getRotation());
    renderer.setColor(new Color(0xffd700ff));
    renderer.circle((getWidth() / 2), (getHeight() / 2) , (getWidth() / 4));
    renderer.end();

    batch.begin();
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
}
```

The problem is, I want my first `image` drawn, then my circle, then a `label` on top of that. However, it seems I can't do this because I can either draw both `image` and `label` on top of the circle, or the circle on top of the other two.

Comment: You will have to create a wrapper Actor class for your circle.

Comment: So create my own actor with nothing in it, other than the shaperender stuff? Yes makes sense, actually it seems too obvious to be true!!

Comment: @Tenfour04 it worked. knock that up as an answer and i'll accept it